# qTip2 - Call a function after changing content of a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I have a qTip tooltip where I'm loading its content via ajax. After the content is loaded I need to call a function someFunction()

```
$('.element').qtip(
{
    content: 
    {
        text: function(event, api) 
        {
            api.elements.content.text('Loading...');

            var content = $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'loadcontent.php',
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .then(function(result) 
            {
                // Some code for changing result html
                return result.html;

            }, function(xhr, status, error) 
            {
                api.set('content.text', 'Error');
            });

            // Calling a function, but it's too early (content is still not in the tooltip)
            someFunction();

            return content;
        }
    }
});
```

To be honest I'm not sure where to put someFunction() so it's called **after** the content is added into the tooltip. There is no event which is fired after the content is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution:

```
$('.element').qtip(
{
    content: 
    {
        text: 'Loading...'
    },
    events: 
    {
        show: function(event, api) 
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'loadcontent.php',
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .then(function(result) 
            {
                api.set('content.text', result.html);

                someFunction();

            }, function(xhr, status, error) 
            {
                api.set('content.text', 'Error');
            });
        }
    }
});
```